# IsSubclassOf not working when loading an assembly

Tags: c#, dll, types, .net-assembly

I am loading an assembly and I get the types contained in it with `assembly.GetTypes()` method. The `GetTypes()` method returns an array of `Type`. I want to filter that array of `Type` in order to get those types that inherit the type `ApiController` (from `System.Web.Http`).

```
var assembly = LoadAssemblyFile("path//to//my//dll");
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
var type = types[1];  // That is the type that inherits ApiController
var x = type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ApiController)); // x is false after execution
```

However, if I create my own project with a base class that inherits a derived class, it works

```
var type = typeof(DerivedClass);  // derived inherits BaseClass
var x = type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)); // x is true now
```

What is the problem? I looked in the type that I want to get and I saw that the property `BaseType` contains the "ApiController" name, so the type contains the inheritance information but the method `IsSubclassOf` doesn't work in that case. Why is this happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in my test project and your code looks fine. Can you make a complete sample, that reproduces the issue

Comment: Did you compile your dll against the same version of ApiController dll (or the dll containing ApiController) as you do in this sample?